# &amp; in URL mess up $_GET variables

Tags: php

We get URLs with `&amp;` instead of `&` from a clients system: `somedomain.com?param1=test&amp;param2=test2`

I expect to get `$_GET['param1']` and `$_GET['param2']`. Instead I get `$_GET['amp;param1']` and `$_GET['amp;param2']`

Do I fix it as an rewrite rule in .htaccess or in PHP?

UPDATE:

A temporary fix is to do the below, but it seems clumsy:

```
foreach ($_GET AS $key => $value)
{
    $param = str_replace('amp;', '', $key);
    $_GET[$param] = $value;
    unset($_GET[$key]);
}
```

Comment: `html_entity_decode`

Comment: Get them to stop sending junk?

Comment: We send an email with the correct link to them. I suspect their email client mess up the link. In this case it is unlikely the client will make changes to their system so it has now become my problem :-(

Comment: $_GET get's populate before I get a chance to do `html_entity_decode`. Of course I can loop through §_GET and replace `amp;` but I think that is a clumsy solution.

Comment: From experience, if you let them "get away with" doing things wrong now, it will always be your problem no matter what they screw up. It's not even like this is because your application is odd, they've completely messed up using a well known and documented standard protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Convert characters `?` and `&` to some tokens like:

`?` to `__Q__` with `str_replace('?', '__Q__', $toUrl)`

`&` to `__AND__` with `str_replace('&', '__AND__', $toUrl)`

And pass this data on url.

While getting this data from url, decode these back.

`str_replace('__Q__', '?', $fromUrl)`

`str_replace('__AND__', '&', $fromUrl)`

Though its tricky, it works.

Comment: I didn't suggest that, I said to get the client to stop sending dodgy data :P

Comment: Ok, removed your reference :)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have define "somedomain.com?param1=test&param2=test2" in HTML. So HTML is converting `&` into `&amp;` reference.

Just try to put `&amp;` instead of `&` like this : `somedomain.com?param1=test&amp;param2=test2`